# Loading Disk image to Ram for boot purposes

Tags: boot, windows-10, memory, bootable-media, ramdisk

I am aware that several versions of linux are capable of being loaded fully into ram for running the os directly as a ram disk.   I am trying to determine the feasibility of doing this with windows 10.  I do not know if this is something that will have to be done at the motherboard firmware level preboot, or if it would require booting a virtual machine and loading said machine into ram (which would have more overhead obviously)   machine is a xeon equipped workstation with 256gb of ddr4.

Simply hoping to get a dialogue started on this.

Comment: It's possible because Windows PE does exactly that.  BartPE was the same done with XP.  Not sure how to convert an existing Windows install to run from a RAM disk, though.

Comment: It wouldn't have to be an existing install.  I'd be reinstalling it from scratch.   I will look into Windows pe

Answer (score 2):

Take a [look](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

**Walkthrough: Create a Bootable Windows PE RAM Disk on CD-ROM**

> This walkthrough describes how you can create a bootable Windows PE
>   RAM disk on CD-ROM by using the Copype.cmd script. Windows PE RAM
>   enables you to start a computer for the purposes of deployment and
>   recovery. Windows PE RAM boots directly into memory, enabling you to
>   remove the Windows PE media after the computer boots.
>
> This method enables you to boot directly into memory and assigns the
>   drive letter X, which does not correspond to the media (USB flash
>   drive or CD-ROM) from which you booted. Ensure that you have
>   sufficient memory to support the size of your Windows PE image plus
>   any additional memory requirements, for example, if you plan on
>   running any customized applications that need additional working
>   memory.

Comment: I will. Look into making my own image hosting this method.  Will have to learn how to copy the image for shut Down. I think restarts after installing new programs may cause the most issue.  I wish I could completely offload this to a separate chipset to manage the mirroring after the main machine shuts down..  But  Thank you.  I will look into this!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bit more geared to what I'm trying to do. It's for a custom windows pe image.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665(v=ws.10).aspx